# How to set text of a label inside a usercontrol c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, label

I am going to design a userControl which contains a textbox and a label.
How can I set a public property for label text?

this is my code:

```
public partial class CurrencyTextBoxWithLable : UserControl
{
    public CurrencyTextBoxWithLable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    private string _lblText;

    public string LabelText 
    {
        get
        {
            return _lblText;
        }
        set
        {
            _lblText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work...
Any help will be appreciated.

DesignerCode:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 6);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = this.LabelText;//Oooppsss!
```

}

[image]

Comment: whats the issue with this.how you tried accessing the label?

Comment: "it doesn't work"...what do you mean?  _What_ doesn't work?

Comment: "It doesn't work" means that when I change the "LabelText" property in "properties" the text of label doesn't change. or when it initialized, it doesn't have the Text

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are overwriting your value from properties. In designer file you are calling this:

```
this.label1.Text = this.LabelText;
```

Looking at your getter, it's returning `_lblText` value:

```
get
{
    return _lblText;
}
```

Since it's not initialized the value of `_lblText` is empty string (""). Try setting value of `_lblText` to some initial value and run your code again. For example add this:

```
private string _lblText = "Label1";
```

**EDIT:**

When you add label to your form it looks like this:

```
this.label1.AutoSize = true;
this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 9);
this.label1.Name = "label1";
this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
this.label1.Text = "label1";
```

So, "label1" is the same value as in properties. When you change it in properties, to lets say `Test label string`, designer will have value of:

```
this.label1.Test = "Test label string";
```

Try removing and adding your label again if it's not working for you. You should be able to change it's value through properties again.

Comment: I tried this but it just initialize the label. How can I set the LablelText Property from properties panel.

Comment: @mohammadboluki not sure I get it, you can by default change it's value from properties panel. check edited answer

Comment: @mohammadboluki Oh I think I get it now, you're trying to set the value of your variable through properties panel. It's impossible by design of visual studio. Visual studio properties panel generates designer file, you can't change the way it works.